# Update a variable in ObservableObject without lagging

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I update variable manually using objectWillChange because I need to change the variable in background to prevent UI lagging.

Normally, appending, removing and changing the mainContent variable in main thread do some lags. ***Check SECOND WAY on below for it.***

Can anyone tell me that am I on the right way? Is this the way that it should be?

**//FIRST WAY**  //no any lags

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    
    var mainContent = [Model]() {
        willSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }

init(){
    fetchItems()
}

func fetchItems(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [self] in
        let fetchedContents = NetworkRequest()
        for content in fetchedContents {
            //lots of append, remove, change iterations for mainContent
            mainContent[x] = bla bla bla
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

}

If I do this way, A little bit lag occurs on the main thread.

**//SECOND WAY**

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
        
      @Published var mainContent = [Model]() 
    
    init(){
        fetchItems()
    }
    
    func fetchItems(){
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [self] in
            let fetchedContents = NetworkRequest()
            for content in fetchedContents {
                //lots of append, remove, change iterations for mainContent
             DispatchQueue.main.async{
             // this places do some lags on the UI
                mainContent[x] = bla bla bla
              }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Thank you for your helps!

Comment: Is this actually a measurable and noticeable difference? To me they seem about the same. I would usually use the 2nd method anyway, because the `@Published` makes it clear that changing this will update its state and also looks cleaner without the `willSet` stuff. Both methods seem valid.

Comment: Hi @George_E, thanks for the reply. I use them for WatchOS app. So it really changes the lag behavior in the UI.

Comment: That will set is a pretty clever idea.

Comment: Is it important that you set `mainContent` on every iteration of the loop, or could you `map` a *new* array first and then do *one* assignment of it to `mainContent` when the operation is done?

Comment: You should probably not make many changes in one "frame". It's probably better to coalesce all the changes into a temporary `[Model]`, then assign it `mainContent` only once. That way, your only receive one onChange message in the views.

Comment: @jnpdx It could be done but if fetchItems function is called multiple time at the same time, most of mainContent data will be lost or not initialized.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper same thing I mentioned on above.

Comment: That seems pretty unlikely, but without a [mre], there is no way to debug this and see what you’re experiencing